# AWS Lambda mock server for E2E testing

Tags: aws-lambda, jestjs, e2e-testing

I have a AWS Lambda service and I have written Unit Tests for it using Jest.
Now I want to extent test to E2Es too, but I am unable to mock the AWS Lambda instance (spin up and tear down)

This is what I want to mock -

```
const endpointUrl = 'http://localhost:5005/my-service';
const customHeaders: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Token mytoken',
      'x-application-api-key': 'my-key'    
    },    
 };    

const response = await axios.get(endpointUrl, customHeaders);
expect(response.status).toBe(200);
```

Is there any tool or library that will help me achive this?